# Can "additional connection parameters be "saved" in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Our staging server has identical settings to the production server which means encrypted communication is turned on, however the staging server has self signed cert which we all know will fail unless TrustServerCertificate=true; is part of the connection string.   When connecting via SSMS all other connection details are remembered from sessions to session except the ones in the additional connection parameters box.

Inevitably I forget, get error, have to click to Options, then Addtional ... enter the string and hit connect again.

Why Microsoft decided that two of the three tabs should be remembered but not the third one is beyond me.

So if there a way around this?
Some config file which specifies the default settings?
So way to launch SSMS from command line including specific connection string and go around it by making a shortcut?

Or am I doomed to forever .... forget. connect. error. options. tab. type. connnect. ?

[image: Additional Connection Parameters]

Comment: Does adding the server as a registered server (Ctrl+Alt+G) help? You can check "Encrypted Connection" there in the connection properties tab but I don't see a field for additional connection parameters, so I'm sceptical. It's worth a try though. Command line has no parameter for generic connection strings either.

Comment: BTW: what hinders you to register the certificate as a trusted certificate to the client computer(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, sorry. The additional parameters are not persisted across sessions.

Since this is something it sounds like you'd like changed I'd suggest submitting a suggestion on the [SQL Server Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer) site and then getting people to vote it up.

UPDATE : This was finally fixed and you should now see the additional parameters field saved just like the other connection options. It's currently only available in the [CTP version of SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) though.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer.  Seems shocking that SSMS lacks this.  It looks like someone else already created a request.  I voted it up.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/813973/the-ssms-connect-to-server-dialog-does-not-persist-the-settings-specified-in-the-additional-connection-parameters-tab

Comment: As my edit mentions this has been fixed in the CTP version of SSMS. You can either start using that (it's backwards compatible with previous versions of SQL) or wait until the official release.

Answer (score 6):

I accepted the answer about no solution, vote it up as that answers the direct solution however I did find a workaround.

In the connection properties of the SQL SERVER (not SSMS) one can force an encrypted connection.   This will require SSMS to connect encrypted regardless of if the "**Encryption connection**" property is set.

Somewhat illogically if the server forces an encryption connection, SSMS will connect without error (or even warning) if the server provides a self signed cert.

To force encrypted connections on SQL SERVER.

1. Start **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.
2. Expand the tree view option **SQL Server Network Configuration**.
3. Right click on **Protocols for INSTANCENAME** and select properties (note this is the actual protocols property not the properties of a specific protocol).
4. On the **Flags** tab set **Force Encryption** to Yes.
5. Restart the SQL Server Instance Service.

You can now connect with SSMS without checking encryption connection and the server will force that encryption regardless.  It seems counter-intuitive in my opinion but there will be no error or warning that you are connecting using a self signed cert.

In SSMS you can verify the encryption status of all active connections the following query (uncomment the last line to show only the current connection):

```
SELECT encrypt_option 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
-- WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

Comment: Perfect and thanks so much for that. Fixed one of the 100 little annoyances and will make my days a lot easier.